# Issue in executing SSL TLS client server Java programs

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, networking, ssl

I have just started studying SSL TLS in Java and written the simple client and server programs. I run the server program first, followed by the client program. On execution, the client program gives the following exception stack trace :-

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at SSLServer.main(SSLServer.java:19)
```

Please let me know the solution to this problem. The server and client programs are as follows :-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;

public class SSLServer {

  private static final int PORT = 8080;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLServerSocket ss = (SSLServerSocket)ssf.createServerSocket(PORT);
    SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket)ss.accept();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while (((line = in.readLine()) != null)) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
    s.close();
  }
}



import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class SSLClient {

  private static final String HOST = "localhost";

  private static final int PORT = 8080;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SSLSocketFactory sf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket)sf.createSocket(HOST, PORT);
    OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
    out.write("\nConnection established.\n\n".getBytes());
    out.flush();
    int theCharacter = 0;
    theCharacter = 5;
    while (theCharacter != '~') // The '~' is an escape character to exit
    {
      out.write(theCharacter);
      out.flush();
      theCharacter = '~';
    }

    out.close();
    s.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the real code? This is usually caused by calling setCipherSuites() somewhere. If you're doing that, remove it.

Comment: This is real code, may be java library is adding setCipherSuites() somwehere in SSLSocket

Answer (score 1):

Let the client and server agree on a common cipher.
Add below code to both server and client.

String[] enableCipherSuite = {"SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5"};
s.setEnabledCipherSuites(enableCipherSuite);